# Get a list of Open Ports in Linux

Tags: linux, ports

I need a Linux command to list all free open ports for use in an application

```
lsof -i TCP| fgrep LISTEN
```

Does not seen to be helping as the Ports it lists are not necessarily free for use. How do I list free open ports not in use?

Answer (score 348, accepted):

```
netstat -lntu
```

as replied by @askmish will give you list of services running on your system on tcp and udp ports where

- `-l` = only services which are listening on some port
- `-n` = show port number, don't try to resolve the service name
- `-t` = tcp ports
- `-u` = udp ports
- `-p` = name of the program

You don't need the 'p' parameter as you're only interested in getting which ports are free and not which program is running on it.

This only shows which ports on your system are used up, though. This doesn't tell you the status of your network e.g. if you're behind NAT and you want some services to be accessible from outside. Or if the firewall is blocking the port for outside visitors. In that case, nmap comes to the rescue. 
WARNING: Use nmap only on networks which are under your control. Also, there are firewall rules which can block nmap pings, you'll have to fiddle around with options to get correct results.

Comment: Note that `netstat` is deprecated on many systems and `ss` should be used instead.

Comment: but if you're on busybox `ss` isn't included

Comment: The big advantage of `netstat` is that it works almost everywhere. On Windows, parameters are a bit different, but it's there, and my Amiga with AmiTCP has it as well, so Linux is the odd one out here. Fortunately, `net-tools` still exists.

Answer (score 149):

Since [`net-tools` is deprecated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146190/commands-not-found-netstat-nmap-on-centos-7), you can use the [`ss` command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ss.8.html) instead of `netstat` if `netstat` is not present on your machine:

```
ss -lntu
```

should work similarly to

```
netstat -lntu
```

according to the built-in help:

```
-n, --numeric       don't resolve service names
-l, --listening     display listening sockets
-t, --tcp           display only TCP sockets
-u, --udp           display only UDP sockets
-p, --processes     show process using socket
```

If you wish to see the processes using each port, and they belong to different users, you need to run

```
sudo ss -lntup
```

Answer (score 27):

This command will list open network ports and the processes that own them:

`netstat -lnptu`

you can thereafter filter the results to your exact specs.

You could also use `nmap` for more granular results about ports.

Comment: The -p flag requires root privileges for some processes, so it would be `sudo netstat -lnptu`

Answer (score 6):

All opened ports including response traffic:

```
netstat -tuwanp 2>/dev/null | awk '{print $4}' | sort | uniq -c | wc -l
```

Comment: A list of *just* unique port numbers and only IPv4: ```netstat -tuwanp4 | awk '{print $4}' | grep ':' | cut -d ":" -f 2 | sort | uniq```

Comment: +1 for showing how to filter and extract the numbers from the result. Edited to remove stderr output from netstat (which adds a header to the result in Ubuntu).

Comment: Hmm, on second thoughts. -1 for not answering the question.

Answer (score 4):

My take on the original question was that he was asking about the unused ports, not the ports currently connected to services.  If this is the case, there's no specific way to list them, other than to listed the used ports and assume the others are unused.

One additional point to keep in mind: as a user, you'll not be able to open a port less than 1024 (you'll need root permissions for that).

Answer (score 1):

The following command will work on any Unix which outputs in the same format as Ubuntu / Debian - where the local address is in the column 4 and the output includes a 2 line header at the top. If either of those numbers is different, tweak the awk command below.

If you want IPv4 only:

```
netstat -lnt | awk 'NR>2{print $4}' | grep -E '0.0.0.0:' | sed 's/.*://' | sort -n | uniq
```

If you want IPv6 only:

```
netstat -lnt | awk 'NR>2{print $4}' | grep -E ':::' | sed 's/.*://' | sort -n | uniq
```

If you want both together:

```
netstat -lnt | awk 'NR>2{print $4}' | grep -E '(0.0.0.0:|:::)' | sed 's/.*://' | sort -n | uniq
```

The command outputs a list of port numbers that are listening on all interfaces. If you want to list all ports that are listening on localhost interface, then use something like this:

```
netstat -lnt | awk 'NR>2{print $4}' | grep -E '(127.0.0.1:|::1:)' | sed 's/.*://' | sort -n | uniq
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo netstat -plnt | grep -E '(0.0.0.0:|:::|127.0.0.1:|::1:)' |  awk 'NR>2{print $7}' | sort -n  | uniq
```

and look at this.

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner to list just unique port numbers and only IPv4:

```
netstat -tuwanp4 | awk '{print $4}' | grep ':' | cut -d ":" -f 2 | sort | uniq
```

All credits to [Aaron C. de Bruyn's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/529830/get-a-list-of-open-ports-in-linux#comment1355030_835177).

Answer (score 0):

```
netstat -an | grep "tcp" | grep "LISTEN" | awk '{print $4}' | grep -wo "....$"
```

lists all open ports that are listening

Comment: And what exactly makes this different from the previously provided answers? Why should OP use `grep` to find listening ports, when `-l` option exists?