# What would prevent a TCP server port (once closed), from being re-opened right away?

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, tcp

I have a server program that uses TCP.

Sometimes, I need to restart the program for updates, or any other reasons, but when I do, the program closes the server port, and then once it restarts, it tries to create a new listener on that port, but it only seems to be able to do that successfully about a minute (~63 seconds) after the port was previously closed. Why would this be, and is there any way to fix it?

The program is running on RamNode's Ubuntu 18.04.

Are there perhaps any settings I can change in the OS, or is it perhaps a RamNode thing, etc.?

Comment: The program might not be cleanly exiting and/or releasing the socket. It might be that the 60 seconds is simply the operating system timing out on the port instead. You might be able to have a script that closes the program, checks every few seconds to see if the port is released and *then* reopens the program. You can see how to list open ports in linux: https://superuser.com/questions/529830/get-a-list-of-open-ports-in-linux

Comment: Did you know that when you try to do an operation and it fails, the implementation gives you some kind of error code that you can look up and from that, probably figure out why it failed. But the likely answer is that the port hasn't been [fully released yet](https://programmer.group/so_reuseaddr-and-so_reuseport-socket-options-for-tcp-ip-programming.html) (due to previous connections not completely and fully dead) and you didn't say that you wanted to allow the port/address to be shared/reused.

Answer (score 0):

For applications dealing with TCP sockets, it's most likely due to the [`TIME-WAIT`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc793#section-3.2) state of the TCP protocol:

> `TIME-WAIT` - represents waiting for enough time to pass to be sure the
> remote TCP received the acknowledgment of its connection termination
> request.

When a previous connection is closed one of the two sides (it depends on which initiated the close) will keep the TCP socket in `TIME-WAIT` state to prevent an identical TCP connection to exist for some time. When this is on the client side it's not a problem, because the port is a random ephemeral port. When it is on a server side with a fixed port and the server is restarted, this prevents the server to bind again on the same port.

---

Here is an example using [`socat`](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) to reproduce the behavior.

term1:

```
socat tcp4-listen:5555 -
```

term2:

```
socat tcp4:127.0.0.1:5555 -
```

Now the connection is established, just interrupt term1's `socat` command. You get the 1mn delay if restarting it right away:

term1:

```
$ socat tcp4-listen:5555 -
2021/07/03 21:32:09 socat[320904] E bind(5, {AF=2 0.0.0.0:5555}, 16): Address already in use
```

The feature to prevent this behavior, especially useful for servers, is the [socket option](https://manpages.debian.org/setsockopt.2) [`SO_REUSEADDR`](https://manpages.debian.org/socket.7):

> `SO_REUSEADDR`
>
> Indicates that the rules used in validating addresses supplied in a
> [bind(2)](https://manpages.debian.org/bind.2) call should **allow reuse of local addresses**. For `AF_INET`
> sockets this means that a socket may bind, except when there is an
> active listening socket bound to the address. When the listening
> socket is bound to `INADDR_ANY` with a specific port then it is not
> possible to bind to this port for any local address. Argument is an
> integer boolean flag.

Instead, when first starting the listening `socat` with:

```
socat tcp4-listen:5555,reuseaddr -
```

even if interrupted after a connection like before, it can now be started again right away without evaluating a TCP connection (this includes a former TCP connection in `TIME-WAIT` state) using this port *if it was also using `SO_REUSEADDR` on the previous run*, for `bind()` to succeed.

Here's a weird example (showing it's not limited to `TIME-WAIT` states):

term1:

```
socat tcp4:127.0.0.1:5555,bind=127.0.0.1:5555,reuseaddr -
```

(Command above connected to itself in a simultaneous TCP initiation, as allowed by [RFC 793](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc793#section-3.4))

```
$ ss -tn sport == 5555
State  Recv-Q  Send-Q   Local Address:Port    Peer Address:Port  
ESTAB  0       0            127.0.0.1:5555       127.0.0.1:5555
```

It won't prevent a listening socket to be created after on port 5555

term2:

```
socat tcp4-listen:5555,reuseaddr
```

term3:

```
$ ss -atnp sport == 5555
State  Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address:Port   Peer Address:Port                                    
LISTEN 0      5            0.0.0.0:5555        0.0.0.0:*     users:(("socat",pid=321093,fd=5)) 
ESTAB  0      0          127.0.0.1:5555      127.0.0.1:5555  users:(("socat",pid=321047,fd=5)) 

$ socat -d -d tcp4:127.0.0.1:5555 -
2021/07/03 22:16:27 socat[322125] N opening connection to AF=2 127.0.0.1:5555
2021/07/03 22:16:27 socat[322125] N successfully connected from local address AF=2 127.0.0.1:52218
2021/07/03 22:16:27 socat[322125] N reading from and writing to stdio
2021/07/03 22:16:27 socat[322125] N starting data transfer loop with FDs [5,5] and [0,1]
```

---

Back to the problem: it's on your application.

Either:

- correct the application to use `setsockopt()` on sockets that will be listening, with `SO_REUSEADDR` to allow `bind()` to succeed despite a connection using that port also existing (`TIME-WAIT` counts as such connection and is the probably only cause in real cases).

or if you can't, on a dynamically linked (with *libc*) application:

- use a wrapper (using [`LD_PRELOAD`](https://manpages.debian.org/ld.so.8#Environment_variables) mechanism) to force your application to do this. Here's a similar (but not same) example in a Q/A answer of mine for `SO_REUSEPORT` which can be adapted easily into `SO_REUSEADDR`: [sshd "listen on all interfaces" behaviour, OSX and Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/1345557/sshd-listen-on-all-interfaces-behaviour-osx-and-ubuntu/1345761#1345761)